# Microsoft Edge IPv6 sites not working

Tags: ipv6, microsoft-edge

I cannot access IPv6-resources in Microsoft Edge. Will support for IPv6 be included in future releases?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions. We do not foretell the future for third-party commercial software products here. If you have questions about that product's future plans, contact the vendor directly and ask them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv6 is most certainly enabled in Edge

[image]

Comment: It was a problem related to using the 6in4-tunneling mechanism. For some reason, Edge wasn't able to use IPv6 if it is used on the same computer that is terminating the tunnel. Browsing from other computers in the network worked well. Without your post I would've never figured that out, though.